# how to display javascript json object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

In Javascript code:

I used this code for display per row of Teams data:

```
var teamlist = {
  "teams0": {
    "name": "Jhon",
    "training": "CEO"
  },
  "teams1": {
    "name": "Alex",
    "training": "Worker"
  }
};

var html = "";
var obj = JSON.parse(teamlist);
for (var i = 0; i < obj.teams.length; i++) {
  html += "<p>" + obj.teams[i].name + "</p>";
}
//jQuery("#searchresults").html(html);
```

In output:

> Uncaught TypeError: obj.teams is undefined

How can I display a JSON object in JavaScript with a `for` loop?

**Update**
this mysql table:
[image]

and in model :

```
public function getMapSearchResults($mapbounds)
{
    try 
    {
        $db    = Factory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('h.name, h.latitude, h.longititude, h.country, h.teams')
           ->from('#__therapist_centers as h')
           ->where('h.latitude > ' . $mapbounds['minlat'] . 
            ' AND h.latitude < ' . $mapbounds['maxlat'] .
            ' AND h.longititude > ' . $mapbounds['minlng'] .
            ' AND h.longititude < ' . $mapbounds['maxlng']);
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $results = $db->loadObjectList(); 
        
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $msg = $e->getMessage();
        Factory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($msg, 'error'); 
        $results = null;
    }

    return $results; 
}
```

and in view php file:

```
function displaySearchResults(result) {
        if (result.success) {
            var html = "";
            
            for (var i=0; i<result.data.length; i++) {
    
                html += "<p>" + result.data[i].name + "</p>"; //worked and display value as well

               html=html+result.data[i].teams;  // dispay ==> {"teams0":{"name":"Jhon","training":"ceo","agenda":""},"teams1":{"name":"Alex","training":"worker","agenda":""}}

               // i want display each teams [name,training] row

             // comment by @Ben-Steinbrunner

              var teamlist = result.data[i].teams;
              for (var key in teamlist) {
              html=html+ '<p>' + teamlist[key].name + '</p>'; // output ==> undefined
           
               }
            }
            jQuery("#searchresults").html(html);  
        } else {
            var msg = result.message;
            if ((result.messages) && (result.messages.error)) {
                for (var j=0; j<result.messages.error.length; j++) {
                    msg += "<br/>" + result.messages.error[j];
                }
            }
            jQuery("#searchresults").html(msg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: your `teamlist` var is essentially an object with key/value pairs (intended for value look-ups like `teamlist.teams0`).  You want to use an array, so `var teamlist = [{"name":"Jhon", "training":"CEO"},...]`. Then consider the [teamlist.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method

Comment: This problem is exactly what the many, many JavaScript template systems were designed to solve.

Comment: @Jack how do it? can you send to me code? thank you

Comment: What's the source of your data?  You're not creating an list; if you want a list then create a list in the first instance.  `var teamlist = '[ { "name":"Jon" }, { "name":"Alex" } ]'`

Comment: One thing that would be helpful would be if you shared an example of your desired output markup.  And also-- how flexible do you need the input parameters to be?  Should this work for any level of depth of nested data?  Or will it always be teams as the first level entries and  team parameters as the second?

Comment: @freedomn-m this var passed from external file. i can not change it.

Comment: @AlexanderNied i updated , please see. thank you

Comment: @AminEbrahimzadeh sorry, only by chance saw this question and didn't have time to post full answer.  hopefully you got it figured out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the external data you can loop over the data with [for-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

```
// emulated data from Database
var result = {};
result.success = true;
result.data = {
        "teams0": {
        "name": "John",
        "training": "CEO"
    },
        "teams1": {
        "name": "Alex",
        "training": "Worker"
    }
};

function displaySearchResults(result) {
    if (result.success) {
        var html = "",
            teamlist = JSON.parse(result.data);
            
        for (var key in teamlist) {
            html += '<p>' + teamlist[key].name + '</p>';
        }
        
        jQuery("#searchresults").html(html);  
    } else {
        var msg = result.message;
        
        if ((result.messages) && (result.messages.error)) {
            for (var j=0; j<result.messages.error.length; j++) {
                msg += "<br/>" + result.messages.error[j];
            }
        }
        
        jQuery("#searchresults").html(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: output ==> undefined

Comment: @AminEbrahimzadeh looking at your updated code and you have a loop in a loop. You only need one loop. I've updated my answer with the additional javascript code you provided emulating data from the database.

Comment: thank you for guide me. but please attention on my database. i need also value of other columns.(just not Teams column)

Comment: before `for` i parse json  `var json = JSON.parse(teamlist);` , now it is worked

Comment: @AminEbrahimzadeh awesome. Glad it worked for you. Sorry I missed the json parse. I'll update my answer for others that may run across this.